# How can I fix a "Segmentation fault" error running "dotnet" command on RasPi?

Tags: linux, .net-core, server, raspberry-pi, arm

I am trying to install the ".NET Core 3.0" runtime on my old Raspberry Pi B+ first gen but I am not able to get it run because of a `Segmentation fault` running the `dotnet` command.

First of all I am using the arm32 version of the binaries, running all commands on a screen session (should not give problems at all), running Raspbian buster lite OS, and using the RasPi as a micro-server for lite-load dev purposes. That's to give some context.

I tried different approaches:

**First**

Downloaded the bins and installed them manually this way

```
sudo apt-get install curl libunwind8 gettext apt-transport-https
wget https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Runtime/release/3.0/dotnet-runtime-latest-linux-arm.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /usr/share/dotnet && sudo tar zxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet
sudo ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet
```

and I recived the error for the first time.

**Second**

Suspecting of a my installation fault i went online and found of a possible missing lib issue related to the error, so I went with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script) another thing I found, which is an installation script directly from Microsoft for the ".NET Core" family, straight after removing the "old" binaries (`sudo rm -r /usr/share/dotnet`) with the following steps

```
wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh
sudo ./dotnet-install.sh --channel Current --architecture arm --runtime dotnet --install-dir /usr/share/dotnet
sudo ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet
```

with no visible results.

**Third**

Thinking about libs I went online for a second time and I tried to figure out the list of needed dependencies to manually install them and the only resource I found is this [dedicated page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore30) on Microsoft's own website lacking of the arm32 dependencies list, so I went for the Ubuntu ones with this line

```
sudo apt install liblttng-ust0 libcurl3  libcurl4  libssl1.0.0 libkrb5-3 zlib1g libicu52 libicu55 libicu57 libicu60 libunwind8 libuuid1
```

but I only got a few installed because of various errors such as "no candidates", "outdated package", "already at newest version", and things like that; same with single installs.

After two days of retrying and doing fresh installs of Raspbian (yes, I also tried that a couple of times) I decided to try the "2.1 LTS" version but I got the exact same result with each of the 3 steps described for the 3.0 version.
As I could expect, I got the same overall result and that's very frustrating.

At this point I also looked for compatibility issues but I could not find something useful.

SO there is the question:
Is there any noticeable compatibility issue, a maybe too old piece of hardware? Can I work around that? And generally, does someone have kinda hint/suggestion/solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2):

.Net Core does not support armv6 cpu, you can install .net core on Pi 2,3,4, but not on Pi.