# Segmentation Fault when running dotnet standalone on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, .net, linux, raspberry-pi, segmentation-fault

Whenever I run a dotnet standalone (compiled on Windows, written in C#) on a Raspberry Pi the Console returns "Segmentation fault".
My Inputs:

```
pi@RevPi230:~/dotnet $ ./PiTest
Segmentation fault
pi@RevPi230:~/dotnet $ sudo ./PiTest
pi@RevPi230:~/dotnet $
```

This problem only occurs on a specific Raspberry Pi, when I run the same build on my second one, the code works just fine. My code is also just the Hello World example code, so I don't think the problem lies within the code.

Running the code in gdb returns the following:

```
Reading symbols from ./PiTest...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pi/PiTest
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00059802 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

When looking for other posts/googling the Problem was always with a specific piece of code (which I tried to rule this out by using the Hello World example, trying other Projects and running the same Build on the second Pi).

Does anyone know what the problem could be or what I can do to further diagnose it?

Articles I have read and tried that didn't help:

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/13-hours-debugging-a-segmentation-fault-in-net-core-on-raspberry-pi-and-the-solution-was

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3013

[How can I fix a "Segmentation fault" error running "dotnet" command on RasPi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640529/how-can-i-fix-a-segmentation-fault-error-running-dotnet-command-on-raspi)

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing on Windows and copying the binaries to the pi, make sure you copy in (not ASCII but) BINARY mode. The recommended tool to copy is scp but that uses ascii mode and converts Windows line endings (cr/lf) to Linux (lf). I used ftp in BINARY mode and the problem went away.